# Group a few threading functions Python

Tags: python, multithreading, grouping

I have a few functions and I want them to be in different threading groups. That is, I want those different threading groups to run after another. My example codes are as below:

```
import threading
from threading import Thread

def func_a():
    # do something here


def func_b():
    # do something here

def func_c():
    # do something here

def func_d():
    # do something here

thread_a = threading.Thread(target = func_a)
thread_b = threading.Thread(target = func_b)
thread_c = threading.Thread(target = func_c)
thread_d = threading.Thread(target = func_d)

thread_a.start()
thread_b.start()
thread_c.start()
thread_d.start()

thread_a.join()
thread_b.join()
thread_c.join()
thread_d.join()
```

What I want to do is very simple: put a `func_a` and `func_b` as `threading_group_a`, also put `func_c` and `func_d` as `threading_group_b`. Then execute `threading_group_a` first and then `threading_group_b`.

Comment: Using `thread_a.join()` and `thread_b.join()` before `thread_c.start()` and `thread_d.start()` is ok? or you want an automatic way of doing this for a higher number of threads?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I do not fully agree, there are situations when you need the results of some operations before being able to process others. Futures and pools are the wya to solve this situations and they seem to be a very legit use case IMO.

Comment: @Adirio, it's not enough to say that *Futures and pools are to be a very legit use case* - it's better to prove it in practice. You can prove it with posting an appropriate answer

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest I'm posting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to use a `Pool`. That's your way to group threads together, and assign them a single task. Then you'll assign a task to the pool, not a specific thread. You've 4 functions, but they do just 2 things. So, you can do this:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def func_a(*args):
    print 1

def func_b(*args):
    print 2

pool = ThreadPool(3)

pool.map(func_a, range(2))
pool.map(func_b, range(2))

11

22
```

Note that I had to change the functions signature, since `pool.map` passes some args to the function. The docs specify *map blocks until result is ready*, so we can remove the `.join()`.

---

Update: yes you can. Let's say you need a + b to be executed together. You can *wrap them* in a third function, which all it does is calling the other two:

```
def ab(*args):
    func_a()
    func_b()
```

Now you pass `ab` function to your threading pool. If you need to return values from the functions, then assign the return values to a list and return that list back.

---

Update 2:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def func_a():
    print 1

def func_b():
    print 2

def ab(*args):
    func_a()
    func_b()

pool = ThreadPool(3)
pool.map(ab, range(2))
```

Comment: Umm... is there any way to put my entire functions inside? Please note my example codes are just examples. What I want to do is to execute a few functions in different threading groups in order.

Comment: @ryan9025 you can do that with a wrapper function. I've updated my answer

Comment: thanks! So I've created a variable `pool = ThreadPool(ab)` . But what about the `pool.map` part?

Comment: @ryan9025 no, you should create a pool and pass *the number of threads* you want in the pool. the `pool.map` is the part where you assign work to your threads. so, `pool = ThreadPool(4)` and then `pool.map(func, range(num_of_iterations))`. Read more on `pool` on the documentation

Comment: Okay but now it retuns `TypeError: 'ThreadPool' object is not callable`?

Comment: You've got something wrong then. Try the code I've added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems to be considered:

1. Thread grouping
2. Flow control

You can go for a manual way, using `list`s or `tuple`s to group the arguments and the threads themselves, and also control the flow manually:

```
from threading import Thread

# Functions for group 1: with no arguments and different fucntions
def func_a():
    print(1)

def func_b():
    print(1)

# Functions for group 2: with a single function but different arguments
def func_c(i):
    print(i)

# Functions for group 3: with different functions and arguments
def func_d(i):
    print(i)

def func_e(i):
    print(i)

funs_1 = (func_a, func_b)
args_2 = ((2,), (2,))
funs_3 = (func_d, func_e)
args_3 = ((3,), (3,))

threads_1 = tuple(Thread(target=func             ) for func in funs_1)
threads_2 = tuple(Thread(target=func_c, args=args) for args in args_2)
threads_3 = tuple(Thread(target=func,   args=args) for func, args in zip(funs_3, args_3))

for thread in threads_1:
    thread.start()

for thread in threads_1:
    thread.join()

for thread in threads_2:
    thread.start()

for thread in threads_2:
    thread.join()

for thread in threads_3:
    thread.start()

for thread in threads_3:
    thread.join()
```

Or use pools, that allow you to specify the ammount of concurrent threads you can have started, and the control will also be handled:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

# Functions for group 1: with no arguments and different fucntions
def func_a():
    print(1)

def func_b():
    print(1)

# Functions for group 2: with a single function but different arguments
def func_c(i):
    print(i)

# Functions for group 3: with different functions and arguments
def func_d(i):
    print(i)

def func_e(i):
    print(i)

funs_1 = (func_a, func_b)
args_2 = ((2,), (2,))
funs_3 = (func_d, func_e)
args_3 = ((3,), (3,))

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as pool:
    futures_1 = tuple(pool.submit(func) for func in funs_1)

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as pool:
    futures_2 = tuple(pool.submit(func_c, *args) for args in args_2)

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as pool:
    futures_3 = tuple(pool.submit(func, *args) for func, args in zip(funs_3, args_3))
```

The `with` statement ensures that the pool will finish all the tasks before exiting. You just need to call the `ThreadPoolExecutor` instance method `submit()` being the first argument the `target` keyword argument equivalent and the rest of positional arguments and keyword-arguments will be passed to the function like the `args` and `kwargs` keyword arguments from `Thread`. `concurrent.futures` is in the standard library for Python3 and has been ported for Python 2.5+, you may need to do `sudo pip install futures`.

Comment: thanks! But I do not quite understand what's the `args_1 = ((1,), (1,))` and `args_2 = ((2,), (2,))`? Does it mean the output of my functions? If so, the situation is that I don't have an output for my functions before it's executed... Is there any other way to put the function itself into the `args` instead of putting the output?  Appreciated!!

Comment: They are the arguments being passed to the functions. I store them in tuples so that I could iterate, but you can check the example of the second group of the ThreadPoolExecutor approach where I don't use the tuple store.

Comment: To simplify, what I want is put the my functions themselves into the `target` inside the `threading`.

Comment: Yeah.. I saw your second one but it still didn't put the entire function as the target.  Also, I would rather use `threading` module for this. Thanks!!

Comment: Yes, thats what I have done. I'm using `print` as the fucntion, you can replace it with whatever name you gave to your fucntion. For example you could replace `future_21 = ...` for `future_21 = pool.submit(my_func)` if you do not need to pass it any argument, or `future_21 = pool.submit(my_func, arg1, arg2, kwarg1=value1, kwarg2=value2)` if you wnat two positional and two keyword arguments.

Comment: `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` is an abstraction over `threading.Thread`, its creating `Threads` and handling the `start()` and `join()` calls itself. If you want to group them manually you will have to go for the first approach. I will edit my answer to use your function names.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I meant... By functions in target I mean `func_a`, `funct_b`, `func_c`, etc.

Comment: Thanks!!  One thing is that pls don't take what the output is in my examples into consideration. Those are just examples and what I want is very simple: put `func_a` and `func_b` as `threading_group_a`, `func_c` and `func_d` as `threading_group_b`. Then execute `threading_group_a` and `threading_group_b` in order.

Comment: I've udnerstood you correctly, take a look now where I have 3 different groups, the first uses two different functions (`func_a` and `func_b`) with no arguments, the second one uses the same func (`func_c`) with different arguments, and the third combines both, different functions and arguments.

Comment: Thanks I'm taking a look at the codes now. I will reply soon